# How to count the columns in my table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to count the total column of my table.

for example

```
   <table>
      <tr>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>66</td>
      </tr>  
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>        
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>        
      </tr>
   </table>
```

The above structure will give me 3 total columns.

I am also doing something for my td.

My codes are like

```
 $("table td").each(function(){
        codes to manipulate td...
 })
```

I was wondering if I can count the maximum column of my table in the above `each` codes.

Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that you look at my answer too. It's more efficient (there are better solutions without the global each) than the selected solution and also takes in account colspans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will count the number of columns in the first row.  It increments the count for those columns that are in the first row (determined using [`.index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)):

```
var cols = 0;
$("table td").each(function(){
    if ($(this).closest("tr").index() == 0) cols++;
})
```

[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/JmCqE/)

---

The following counts the maximum number of columns in the table (useful if the rows have variable column counts):

```
var maxColumns = Math.max.apply(null, $("table tr").map(function() { 
    return $(this).find("td").length; 
}));
```

[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Txjsj/1/)

Answer (score 2):

`$("table td").length` will return all the columns on the table which is (6) not what you want.

`$("table tr:eq(0) td").length`, will give you the number of columns in the first row.

Comment: thanks lbu, but I was hoping I can write some codes inside my each function. +1 though.

Comment: Please note that this will note take colspans in account.

Comment: @plalx you are correct, that will require a little more engineering

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.max.apply(null, $("table tr").map(function(_,row) { return $(row).find("td").length; }))
```

Answer (score 0):

> thanks lbu, but I was hoping I can write some codes inside my each
>   function

You can, but it's not as clean...

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nJq4N/)

```
var maxCols = 0,
    firstTr = $('table tr:first-child')[0];

$("table td").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.parent()[0] === firstTr) {
        maxCols += parseInt($this.attr('colspan'), 10) || 1;
    }
});
```

*Note: This would account for colspans too.*

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, most performant and most reusable solution I could think of is:

```
function colCount($table) {
  return $table.find('tr').eq(0).children().length;
}

var cols = colCount($('table#myTable'));
```